# SSMS removing pre-BEGIN comments from my stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I'm running SSMS 12.0.2000.8

If I use the SSMS query editor to create a stored procedure (such as the one below) the comments before `BEGIN` are removed when I execute/save it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc
/* Say goodbye to this comment */
    @var1 int -- this comment will disappear too
AS
BEGIN
   /* This comment is safe */
   select 'hello' -- this too shall endure
END
```

A colleague is running the same version of SSMS and has no such problems. If I execute one of his scripts using `sqlcmd.exe` the comments get stripped then too. I presume there must be a global setting that I need to change but I have no idea where it might be.

Comment: What do you mean by "then script it". Are you taking it out from the database with management studio? There's a lot of settings for that which you probably need to check.

Comment: I have no idea why I wrote 'script it' - must have been a Friday afternoon brain fart. I'm creating the SP in the SSMS query editor, and using Script Stored Procedure As... to view the result.

Comment: Have you checked all the options related to that? By default it leaves out a lot of things. Don't have access to SSMS now so I can't check if that's there too.

Comment: Is your colleague using the exact same database and creating the exact same procedure? There are things that can modify a statement in transit (like DDL triggers). For what it's worth, I cannot reproduce this using SSMS 12.0.2456.0, and indeed I'd be highly surprised, since it just has to execute my command as-is and not chop it up in an interesting fashion. If all else fails, try a profiler trace to verify the right command is sent to SQL Server.

Comment: @JamesZ I'm not sure which particular options you mean, but I've been through pretty much every menu item in SSMS and so far come up with nothing.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I tried your profiler suggestion, and from what I could see it was sending the full text to SQL Server. My colleague is running the exact same database, etc. I even tried exporting his settings and importing them into my SSMS but no joy. I may try a reinstall and see if that helps.

Comment: SSMS also uses SQL to retrieve the stored procedure text, you could compare the profiler trace of that with what your colleague is seeing... but that's a bit out there. If all else fails, you can always forego scripting and use `select [definition] from sys.sql_modules where object_id = object_id('MySproc')`, I suppose. :-)

Comment: I just tried using the SQL Server Object Explorer inside Visual Studio 2013 and it worked - comments were preserved when creating the SP, and even SPs created via SSMS show all the comments when I do 'Script As'. SSMS is definitely causing mischief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After observing some other strangeness (namely `with execute as caller` being added to my scripts), I did some Googling and discovered the answer:

```
delete \Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\12.0\sqlstudio.bin
```

**WARNING:** You will lose your current list of memorized SQL Servers/usernames/passwords.

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing the same issue and found that it was caused by Tools -> Options -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> Scripting -> Convert user-defined data types to base types.

When this is "True" I lose my comment blocks. When "False" my comment blocks came back.

Comment: Curiously enough, this seems to be the favoured workaround for a current burning issue: [SSMS 2016 16.4 fails when attempting to ALTER/Modify a Stored Procedure: Syntax error in TextHeader of StoredProcedure](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3103831)

Comment: in my case this setting apparently makes no difference - still have the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this with SQL Server 2008 and SSMS 12.0.2000.8, and this was the result after "Script stored procedure as" - > "Create to" -> "Clipboard":

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
/* Say goodbye to this comment */
    @var1 int -- this comment will disappear too
AS
BEGIN
   /* This comment is safe */
   select 'hello' -- this too shall endure
END
GO
```

Have you tried checking with sp_helptext if the comments are in the procedure before you use the scripting tool?

I also checked the options, can't find anything there related to comments, or stripping away anything like that.

Comment: I wish I'd known about sp_helptext. Anyway, SQL Server Object Explorer inside Visual Studio 2013 revealed that that comments were not being stripped, and after deleting sqlstudio.bin the problem went away. It definitely appears that the SSMS scripting engine got itself into a weird state.

Answer (score 1):

While the specified solutions didn't work for me, it certainly pointed me in the right direction.

For me, the behavior was only occurring on a single SQL Server connection, and it was because "Always Encrypted" was set to "enable".  When I disabled it, my comments remained in the stored procedure code.

[Screen Shot of SSMS 18.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EryVC.png)