# SQL Server - Unable to put comments in procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I create procedure

```
/*
 This comment does will disappear
*/
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_123]  
AS
BEGIN
/*
 This comment does will disappear
*/

--This comment does will disappear
SELECT 1 AS Test

END
```

On my instance of the DB creates it like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_123]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS Test;
END
```

Running it in a different DB I get the expected result.

What caused the comments to disappear?

Useful info : I have the RedGate tool-belt installed (maybe it could be related)
I'm running SQL Server 14.0.2027.2

Comment: I can't replicate this problem, and I use Redgate Toolbelt as well. Where (and when) is it you're seeing that the comments are being stripped out from?

Comment: What do you mean the comments disappear? Are you saying that if you right click in explorer and select modify those comments are removed? What about looking here? select definition from sys.sql_modules
where object_id = object_id('test_123') What you are describing is not reproducible for me.

Comment: Gosh!  Not only did it remove your comments (which shouldn't happen btw), but it added a missing `;` to your `SELECT` statement, then indented it... looks like some sort of formatting is going on?

Comment: @Lamu I see it in the Profiler.  Also I see it when I try to modify the procedure.

Comment: So you are saying that it is being changed before the batch executes? The comments are removed in Profiler and when modifying the query? If that is the case you have something on your system doing it because that is not going to happen with SSMS.

Comment: @RichardHansell  It does indeed.  But i've searched on config that could cause the behavior and I'm a bit out of Ideas.

It seems to be unreleated to the Database itself but more the instance as this behavior happens on all the db in the instance on of them is AdventureWorks.

Comment: Completely agree with @SeanLange; I had a good scan of the options within SQL Prompt (which would be the most likely candidate) and there is nothing in there that forces the running of a batch to have the style formatting executed, nor for comments to be deleted (there isn't an option to do that at all), **before** the batch is executed. Style formatting is a manual operation (by clicking the button/menu option or using `CTRL+K,CTRL+Y`

Comment: I think you guys lack information to help me.

What info could I provide to make it easier for you?

Comment: What you are describing is not reproducible.

Comment: If what you say is happening, truly is what's happening then this is either by some add on you have installed (I very much doubt it's a RedGate tool doing it), or something in your server; however considering you say that the query is lacking the comments in profiler this points at an SSMS add-on (other than Redgate's).

Comment: This could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624224/ssms-removing-pre-begin-comments-from-my-stored-procedures

Comment: @RichardHansell  
I seen this answer.  Tried to delete the sqlstudio.bin it did not do anything. 

Note In the question the Gary Chapman was having a comment that would survive  and only the comment in the before the Procedure was removed. 

All the comments in the procedure are removed in my case.

Comment: @Larnu   I have no other AddOn then the Redgate one.

But I fully agree with you that it seems to be related to my SSMS since I did 

 EXEC sp_executesql N'/* This comment does will disappear*/CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_123]  AS BEGIN /* This comment does will disappear*/SELECT 1 AS Test END'

and the comments remained